# The "comme pour mieux nous cacher que le logos, [...], nous trahit" quandary

Tags: grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques, verbes

> Les philosophes semblent vouloir se rassurer en répétant que les sens
>   nous trompent, `comme pour` `mieux nous cacher` que le logos, langage
>   et raison, nous trahit.

First of all, I would like to know if *comme pour* means *as if*.

Then, when combined with *mieux nous cacher*, if the whole fragment (*comme pour mieux nous cacher*) could be rendered in English as *as if we'd better hide*.

Finally, assuming I haven't made a single mistake so far, how would the two already discussed fragments (`comme pour` and `mieux nous cacher`) make any sense when coupled with the rest of the quotation: *que [...] nous trahit*?

Somehow, when put together, the three fragments (`comme pour`, `mieux nous cacher`, and `que [...] nous trahit`) seem to lose all cohesion.

Comment: I would have voted to close with “too localized”, this question is not applicable to a large audience (but I can't any more since the voting system changed). You should narrow down your question to a specific point.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez What about Off-topic > Other > Too localized? It's a valid reason for closing in my opinion...

Comment: _Philosophers seem to want to comfort themselves by repeating that the senses deceive us, as to better hide us that the logos, language and reason betrays us._

Comment: I thought this was a site dedicated to those in the business of learning whatever it is they learn. In my case, French and German. As an autodidact, I'm learning these languages on my own. So I have no one to turn to for help but for this site. And now I see I am being sent off because my question was either too general or too narrow. Well, perhaps this policy is not very good as it seems not to be designed for every kind of need that a learner of foreign languages might indeed have. Textual analysis should really be available as a learning tool. So everyone should be open-minded about it.

Comment: First of all, don't take it personnally. **You** are not being sent off, the **validity of your question** is being openly **discussed**, and actually it's not been neither downvoted nor flagged for closing. This is a Q&A website. Questions asked here (and the answers provided, if any) should be useful for future readers, not only for the one asking at one moment in time. Most of the questions you asked so far were perfectly fine, since they dealt with specific idiomatic expressions other people might face in the future. However, it's not the case of the sentence you are asking about here.

Comment: I think this question could be useful for people in the future.  It certainly is localized but I don't think this hurts the validity of the question.  95 percent of the questions I see on Stack Overflow are specific code problems with specific error reports, asking for help.  If the above question is too localized, then Stack Overflow should close down the majority of the questions being asked for this problem.  Users may find this question on a search engine and find it helpful.  You can't foresee if this will happen.

Comment: So many people get frustrated with the SE model because people take it too far with the moderation I think.  **I think if you want a successful French Q&A site, relax on the criticism a little bit**.

Comment: @Patrick Sebastien Exactly. There is only so much you can ask, grammatically, as grammar itself is a restricted code of rules. Hence: finite. Grammatical questions are, therefore, finite in number. That's why, I think, such a site as this should also be dedicated to contextual, yet still grammar-dependent, questions, which is the best way that learners can be encouraged to deepen their knowledge of French (in this particular case) by reading as much as possible. The future of this very site may very well depend upon it (as grammar is inherently a finite code of rules).

Comment: I think the underlying question is fine, but the current formulation makes some people queasy. You basically have a "what does this phrase mean, why is it constructed this way" question, but your (very commendable) attempt to explain it yourself covers it up some and makes it look like it'd only be helpful to you, and we try to avoid those kinds of question. But I don't think it's one. You could either edit it to clear that up if you wanted, but I don't think anything is going to be done to it if you leave it as is.

Comment: @Kareen I am not an absurd person. As I'm a new member of this community, I'm obviously trying to absorb your way of doing things. So I'm trying to refine my posting skills. On the other hand, though, I have unfortunately noticed (just) a tinge of narrow-mindedness on the part of some users when it comes to new members and their way of thinking about the form they would like to be helped in. While I'll do my very best to respect the community and adjust to its rules, I will never accept the elegant bullying I've been subjected to; hence my official protest, which you have likely already read.

Comment: @Kareen Anyway, I do hope I'll have a long happy life on this site: full of things to learn, (virtually) surrounded by a great community of knowledge seekers just like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to break down the sentence correctly.

> …, (comme pour (mieux nous cacher que ((le logos, langage et raison,) nous trahit))).

*Le logos, language et raison*: *langage et raison* is in apposition to *logos*. Semantically, this could be written “*le logos (qui est langage et raison)*”.

Thus this sentence fragment is a nuance on “*comme pour mieux nous cacher que le logos nous trahit*”, i.e. (translated litterally) “as if to hide from us the fact that *logos* betrays us”. The semantic subject of *cacher* is *les philosophes*, not *nous*. The pronoun *nous* is a complement of the verb *cacher*: hide *from* us. If you substitute mankind for *nous*, the sentence could be written “… *comme pour mieux cacher à l'humanité que le logos la trahit*”.

Another way to write the sentence with a similar meaning would be “*comme s'ils voulaient nous cacher que le logos nous trahit*” (where *ils* = *les philosophes*).

*Comme* indicates that what follows appears to be true but is probably not completely correct — either a simile or a misleading appearance.

Comment: Are all your answers so great? I see you're a real fountain of knowledge. Again, thank you for your invaluable help.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the complete fragment you are interested in is *comme pour mieux nous cacher **que** ...* , meaning that the object of the verb *cacher* is not ourselves, but the fact that the logos fools us.

The correct meaning would be

> ... as if they wanted to hide from us the fact that the logos, speech and reason, fools us.